# How do I get a reference to the status bar in iOS 13+?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to blur the status bar like in Apple Maps. There are some solutions I've found on the internet but they're all a couple of years old at least and refer to deprecated properties, so I'e been trying to come up with a solution that works for iOS 13+ without any warnings.

Here's what I've tried:

```swift
func blurStatusBar() {
    let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })
    if let statusBarFrame = window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame {
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .regular))
        blurEffectView.frame = statusBarFrame
        view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work. Using the debugger, I can see that `window` is `nil`, so it appears there are no windows that are set as the key window.

If I use `let statusBarFrame = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame`, it works, however I get a warning: `ViewController.swift:66:51: 'statusBarFrame' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Use the statusBarManager property of the window scene instead.`

I am calling the above function in `viewDidLoad` from my initial view controller. Is this something I should be doing in my scene delegate instead of view controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in comedy, timing is everything. `viewDidLoad` is too soon. Your view controller has a view, but that view is not yet necessarily in a window and there is not yet necessarily a key window. Wait until something like `viewDidLayoutSubviews` when the initial interface hierarchy has been assembled  (and add a check to make sure you don’t run the same code twice).

Comment: Thanks. Could you shed some light on why it works using the deprecated `UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame` even from `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Because the application does exist. But your proposed workaround depends on the key window, which doesn’t.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, it works with `viewDidAppear` but not `viewWillAppear` - I guess that's still too early. I tried to edit your answer but I am not sure that it worked.

Comment: `viewDidAppear` is too late, as the user will see a flash. Try `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.